To whom or what did Jesus address Ephphatha?
We read in Mk 7:35( NKJV) how Jesus heals a deaf man:

Then, looking up to heaven, He sighed, and said to him, “Ephphatha,” that is, “Be opened”.

Some versions like NET do not use the words " to him" implying that the command was not necessarily addressed to the deaf man, but to someone/something else.
If Jesus did address the man, it would mean that the latter had already been healed, and was able to hear. ( Well, Jesus also told the dead daughter of Jairus to get up (Mk 5:41), but then, there were witnesses who could hear him ).Is it possible that the Lord addressed the man's 'closed' ears and commanded them to open up,  just as he rebuked  the storm and commanded the waves to calm down  ( Mk 4:39) ? My question therefore is: To whom OR what did Jesus address Ephphatha ?

The Greek text of Mark 7:34 is undisputed and thus the word αὐτῷ (= "to him") is not disputed.
In performing this miracle, let us examine the previous verse as well:

Mark 7:33-35 - So Jesus took him aside privately, away from the crowd,
and put His fingers into the man’s ears. Then He spit and touched the
man’s tongue. And looking up to heaven, He sighed deeply and said to
him, “Ephphatha!” (which means, “Be opened!”). Immediately the man’s
ears were opened and his tongue was released, and he began to speak
plainly.

Note several things about this narrative:

it was done away from the crowd or anyone else and thus, only Jesus the man were present
the only viable grammatical antecedent of "him" is the man
as if to confirm this, "immediately the man's ears were opened"; the "to him" must still be the man that was healed.


Thanks, Dottard. But how could the person be treated as ' closed' so as to necessitate the command :" be opened' ?

@KadalikattJosephSibichan - I do not know; however, I also note that when Jesus stood in front of the grave of Lazarus and said, "Lazarus come forth", despite being dead, Lazarus heard Jesus and was resurrected.  Please do not ask me to explain divine miracles - they are beyond human understanding.

Thanks, Dottard. It was not required of Jesus to utter any word in order to perform a miracle. If he did say something,  it was for those who were around. That Jesus took the deaf man away from the crowd does not mean that the disciples were also stopped from witnessing the miracle ; does it ?

" And He took him aside from the multitude " is what NKJV says in Mk 7:34.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan - true - and what is your point.

My point is that a  couple of disciples including Mark, not being part of the multitude, were privy to the miracle and that Jesus commanded the man's 'closed ' ears to open.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan - we do not know that.  Many things are recorded in the gospels to which the disciples were not witness.
